# Signed measure, a sort of integral triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure. Define$$\int f\,d\nu = \int f\,d\nu^+ - \int f\,d\nu^-.$$Do we necessarily have that$$\left| \int f\,d\nu\right| \le \int |f|\,d|\nu|?$$

Comment: A related question ... what is the proper way to define $|\nu|$ for a complex measure $\nu$, so that $\left| \int f\,d\nu\right| \le \int |f|\,d|\nu|$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left|\int f\ \mathsf d\nu\right| &= \left|\int f\ \mathsf d\nu^+ - \int f\ \mathsf d\nu^-\right|\\
&\leqslant \left|\int f\ \mathsf d\nu^+\right| + \left|\int f\ \mathsf d\nu^-\right|\\
&\leqslant \int |f|\ \mathsf d\nu^+ + \int |f|\ \mathsf d\nu^-\\
&= \int |f|\ \mathsf d|\nu|.
\end{align}